# Need drop down menu

Tags: jquery, menu

I need a drop down menu.  There are so many out there, is there a jquery drop down menu that's fairly simple with total CSS configuration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like this one: http://purecssmenu.com/ but it's not jQuery, it's just CSS.

However, I'm sure this question has been asked before, I'd search.